# Tabulator - Filter by date range ( from / to) in Header

Tags: filter, header, tabulator

Is there a way to implement Date Range Filters in the column header of a Tabulator table?

Answer (score 3):

The [Header Filter Example Docs](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.8#filter-header) include an example of a max min header filter for integers.

Based on this we can look at making our own custom header filter for date ranges, in this example i am going to use the built in `Date` object but you can choose any date library that works for you. We will also assume that dates will be entered in the YYYY-MM-DD format, you can use which ever date picker library you would like instead

So to start with we will create out custom filter editor *(this will build the header filter elements)*

```js
//custom max min header filter
var minMaxFilterEditor = function(cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams){

    var end;

    var container = document.createElement("span");

    //create and style inputs
    var start = document.createElement("input");
    start.setAttribute("type", "date");
    start.setAttribute("placeholder", "Min");
    start.style.padding = "4px";
    start.style.width = "50%";
    start.style.boxSizing = "border-box";

    start.value = cell.getValue();

    function buildValues(){
        success({
            start:start.value,
            end:end.value,
        });
    }

    function keypress(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            buildValues();
        }

        if(e.keyCode == 27){
            cancel();
        }
    }

    end = start.cloneNode();
    end.setAttribute("placeholder", "Max");

    start.addEventListener("change", buildValues);
    start.addEventListener("blur", buildValues);
    start.addEventListener("keydown", keypress);

    end.addEventListener("change", buildValues);
    end.addEventListener("blur", buildValues);
    end.addEventListener("keydown", keypress);


    container.appendChild(start);
    container.appendChild(end);

    return container;
 }
```

Then we will create out filter function that filters by these date ranges:

```js
//custom max min filter function
function minMaxFilterFunction(headerValue, rowValue, rowData, filterParams){
    //headerValue - the value of the header filter element
    //rowValue - the value of the column in this row
    //rowData - the data for the row being filtered
    //filterParams - params object passed to the headerFilterFuncParams property

    //convert strings into dates

    if(headerValue.start != ""){
        headerValue.start = new Date(headerValue.start);
    } 
    if(headerValue.end != ""){
        headerValue.end = new Date(headerValue.end );
    }
    
    //compare dates
    if(rowValue){
        rowValue = new Date(rowValue);

        if(headerValue.start != ""){
            if(headerValue.end != ""){
                return moment(rowValue) >= headerValue.start && rowValue <= headerValue.end;
            }else{
                return rowValue >= headerValue.start;
            }
        }else{
            if(headerValue.end != ""){
                return rowValue <= headerValue.end;
            }
        }
    }

    return true; //must return a boolean, true if it passes the filter.
}
```

Then we can assign these to a column in its column definition object using the ***headerFilter*** and ***headerFilterFunc*** peroperties:

```js
{title:"Date of Birth", field:"dob", width:150, headerFilter:minMaxFilterEditor, headerFilterFunc:minMaxFilterFunction, headerFilterLiveFilter:false},
```

Comment: Thank you Oli Folkerd

Comment: no problem, if you found this helpful, would you mind marking it as the answer to help other users find it

Comment: Works well,
but the function minMaxFilterFunction
 
`return moment(rowValue) >= headerValue.start && rowValue <= headerValue.end;`

should be

`return rowValue >= headerValue.start && rowValue <= headerValue.end;`

Moment library is not necessary for this timestamp comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works but I want it to filter one date when only startdate is mentioned and between dates when two dates are mentioned. How can we achieve this?

Comment: You would adapt your custom filter function to contain the logic for that

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Table</title>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.6.2/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="dist/css/bootstrap/tabulator_bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css'> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.6.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js'></script>

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet'>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />

</head>
<style>
body {
font-family: 'Lato';font-size: 22px;
}
.tabulator-row.tabulator-row-even {
background-color: #fbfcfd;
}
.tabulator-row .tabulator-cell {    
border-right: 1px solid #e7ecf1;    
}
.tabulator .tabulator-header .tabulator-col {

border-right: 1px solid #d4d4d4;

}
</style>

<body>

<!--<table id="example-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="200">11111</th>
        <th tabulator-align="center">2222</th>
        <th>3333</th>
        <th>4444</th>
        <th width="150">555555</th>
        <th>6</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>    
        <td>Billy Bob</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>male</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>red</td>
        <td>22/04/1994</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mary May</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>female</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>blue</td>
        <td>14/05/1982</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>-->


<div style="padding:0px 0px 20px 0px">
<button id="reactivity-add">Add New Row</button>
<button id="reactivity-delete">Remove Row</button>
<button id="reactivity-update">Update First Row Name</button>
<button id="hidecar" onclick="hidecol('car')">Hide Driver Col</button>
<button id="showcar" onclick="showcol('car')">Show Driver Col</button>
</div>
<div id="example-table"></div>
<script>

//**********define row context menu starts*****************
var headerMenu = [
{
    label:"Hide Column",
    action:function(e, column){
        column.hide();
    }
    
},
]

//**********define row context menu ends*****************



//************Create Date Editor starts*****************
var dateEditor = function(cell, onRendered, success, cancel){
//cell - the cell component for the editable cell
//onRendered - function to call when the editor has been rendered
//success - function to call to pass the successfuly updated value to Tabulator
//cancel - function to call to abort the edit and return to a normal cell

//create and style input
var cellValue = moment(cell.getValue(), "DD/MM/YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
input = document.createElement("input");

input.setAttribute("type", "date");
input.style.padding = "4px";
input.style.width = "100%";
input.style.boxSizing = "border-box";
input.value = cellValue;

onRendered(function(){
    input.focus();
    input.style.height = "100%";
});

function onChange(){
    if(input.value != cellValue){
        success(moment(input.value, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
    }else{
        cancel();
    }
}

//submit new value on blur or change
input.addEventListener("blur", onChange);

//submit new value on enter
input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        onChange();
    }

    if(e.keyCode == 27){
        cancel();
    }
});

return input;
};

//************Create Date Editor ends*****************


var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {

 layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
 responsiveLayout:"hide",//Responsive
 //selectable:true,//highlight row on select
 height:"auto",
 //maxHeight:"100%", 
 height:"335px",
 tooltips:true,  
 fitColumns:true,
 rowContextMenu: "rowMenu", //add context menu to rows
 addRowPos:"top",
 scrollToRowPosition    :"top",  
 footerElement:"<button>Custom Button</button>",
 movableRows: true, //Drag and Drop Rows
 movableColumns: true, //Drag and Drop column   
 resizableRows:true,       //allow row order to be changed
 history:true,             //allow undo and redo actions on the table
 paginationSize:7,         //allow 7 rows per page of data  
 virtualDomHoz:true,
 reactiveData:true, //turn on data reactivity    
 data:"tabledata", //load data into table
 

rowClick:function(e, row){ //trigger an alert message when the row is clicked
    //alert("Row " + row.getData().id + " Clicked!!!!");
},


//tooltip
tooltips:function(cell){
    //cell - cell component
    //function should return a string for the tooltip of false to hide the tooltip
    return  cell.getColumn().getField() + " - " + cell.getValue(); //return cells "field - value";
},


//Filters
 headerFilterPlaceholder:"filter data...", //set column header placeholder text
columns:[
{title:"", field:"",  cssClass: "text-underline", headerSort:false, headerFilter:true, headerFilter:"input", formatter:"rowSelection", frozen:true, titleFormatter:"rowSelection", width:50, hozAlign:"center",  cellClick:function(e, cell){cell.getRow().toggleSelect();}},
    {title:"Name",  field:"name", headerFilter:true, headerFilterPlaceholder:"Search Name..", headerFilter:"select",responsive:0,editor:"input", validator:["minLength:3", "maxLength:10", "string"],headerMenu:headerMenu},        
    {title:"Progress", headerMenu:"headerMenu",headerFilter:"select", field:"progress", width:150, formatter:"progress", sorter:"number", headerFilterPlaceholder:"Filter by (%)..",headerMenu:headerMenu},     
    {title:"Gender", headerMenu:"headerMenu", field:"gender", responsive:0,  editor:"select", editorParams:{"male":"Male", "female":"Female"}, headerFilter:true, headerFilterPlaceholder:"Select Gender", headerFilterParams:{"male":"Male", "female":"Female"},headerMenu:headerMenu},
    {title:"Rating",  headerMenu:"headerMenu", field:"rating", editor:"star", align:"center",  responsive:0,headerFilter:"number", headerFilterPlaceholder:"at least...", headerFilterFunc:">=",headerMenu:headerMenu},
    {title:"Favourite Color", headerMenu:"headerMenu",field:"col",  headerFilter:"input",responsive:0,headerMenu:headerMenu},   
    {title:"Date of Birth", field:"dob", width:150, headerFilter:minMaxFilterEditor, headerFilterFunc:minMaxFilterFunction, headerFilterLiveFilter:false},


   {title:"Driver", field:"car", hozAlign:"center", formatter:"tickCross",  headerFilter:"tickCross",  headerFilterParams:{"tristate":true},headerFilterEmptyCheck:function(value){return value == null},headerMenu:headerMenu},       
   {title:"", field:"", width:50, headerMenu:headerMenu, headerSort:false,allowEmpty:true, allowTruthy:true, tickElement:"<i class='fa fa-check'></i>", crossElement:"<i class='fa fa-times'></i>"},
    
    
],

 initialSort:[             //set the initial sort order of the data
    {column:"name", dir:"asc"},
],
//freeze first row on data load
/*dataLoaded:function(data){ 
    var firstRow = this.getRows()[0];

    if(firstRow){
        firstRow.freeze();
    }
},*/

//pagination
pagination:"local", //enable local pagination.
paginationAddRow:"table",   
paginationSizeSelector:[7, 10, 15, 20, 25],
movableColumns:true,


});



//add row to bottom of table on button click
document.getElementById("reactivity-add").addEventListener("click", function(){
tabledata.push({name:"IM A NEW ROW", progress:100, gender:"male"});
});

//remove bottom row from table on button click
document.getElementById("reactivity-delete").addEventListener("click", function(){
tabledata.pop();
});

//update name on first row in table on button click
document.getElementById("reactivity-update").addEventListener("click", function(){
tabledata[0].name = "IVE BEEN UPDATED";
});

//*****Show hide columns with buttons starts*********************
const columns = table.getColumns(true);

hidecol = (colName) => {
columns.forEach((col) => {
  if (col.getDefinition().field === colName) {
    col.hide();
  }
});
}


showcol = (colName) => {
columns.forEach((col) => {
  if (col.getDefinition().field === colName) {
    col.show();
  }
});
}
//*****Show hide columns with buttons ends*****************


//****************************Create Date Editor Starts*************************

var dateEditor = function(cell, onRendered, success, cancel){
//cell - the cell component for the editable cell
//onRendered - function to call when the editor has been rendered
//success - function to call to pass the successfuly updated value to Tabulator
//cancel - function to call to abort the edit and return to a normal cell

//create and style input
var cellValue = moment(cell.getValue(), "DD/MM/YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
input = document.createElement("input");

input.setAttribute("type", "date");

input.style.padding = "4px";
input.style.width = "100%";
input.style.boxSizing = "border-box";

input.value = cellValue;

onRendered(function(){
    input.focus();
    input.style.height = "100%";
});

function onChange(){
    if(input.value != cellValue){
        success(moment(input.value, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
    }else{
        cancel();
    }
}

//submit new value on blur or change
input.addEventListener("blur", onChange);

//submit new value on enter
input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        onChange();
    }

    if(e.keyCode == 27){
        cancel();
    }
});

return input;
};

//****************************Create Date Editor Ends*************************


//custom max min header filter
var minMaxFilterEditor = function(cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams){

var end;

var container = document.createElement("span");

//create and style inputs
var start = document.createElement("input");
start.setAttribute("type", "date");
start.setAttribute("placeholder", "Min");
start.style.padding = "4px";
start.style.width = "50%";
start.style.boxSizing = "border-box";

start.value = cell.getValue();

function buildValues(){
    success({
        start:start.value,
        end:end.value,
    });
}

function keypress(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        buildValues();
    }

    if(e.keyCode == 27){
        cancel();
    }
}

end = start.cloneNode();
end.setAttribute("placeholder", "Max");

start.addEventListener("change", buildValues);
start.addEventListener("blur", buildValues);
start.addEventListener("keydown", keypress);

end.addEventListener("change", buildValues);
end.addEventListener("blur", buildValues);
end.addEventListener("keydown", keypress);


container.appendChild(start);
container.appendChild(end);

return container;
}



//custom max min filter function
function minMaxFilterFunction(headerValue, rowValue, rowData, filterParams){
//headerValue - the value of the header filter element
//rowValue - the value of the column in this row
//rowData - the data for the row being filtered
//filterParams - params object passed to the headerFilterFuncParams property

//convert strings into dates

if(headerValue.start != ""){
    headerValue.start = new Date(headerValue.start);
} 
if(headerValue.end != ""){
    headerValue.end = new Date(headerValue.end );
}

//compare dates
if(rowValue){
    rowValue = new Date(rowValue);

    if(headerValue.start != ""){
        if(headerValue.end != ""){
            return moment(rowValue) >= headerValue.start && rowValue <= headerValue.end;
        }else{
            return rowValue >= headerValue.start;
        }
    }else{
        if(headerValue.end != ""){
            return rowValue <= headerValue.end;
        }
    }
}

return true; //must return a boolean, true if it passes the filter.
}



//date ranges

$(function() {
var table = $("#example").DataTable();

// Date range vars
minDateFilter = "";
maxDateFilter = "";

$("#daterange").daterangepicker();
$("#daterange").on("apply.daterangepicker", function(ev, picker) {
minDateFilter = Date.parse(picker.startDate);
maxDateFilter = Date.parse(picker.endDate);

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
var date = Date.parse(data[1]);

if (
(isNaN(minDateFilter) && isNaN(maxDateFilter)) ||
(isNaN(minDateFilter) && date <= maxDateFilter) ||
(minDateFilter <= date && isNaN(maxDateFilter)) ||
(minDateFilter <= date && date <= maxDateFilter)
) {
return true;
}
return false;
});
table.draw();
}); 


});

//**************************define row context menu contents Ending)**********************

var tabledata = [
{id:1, name:"Andy", progress:100, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"red",height:1, dob:"8/10/2020", car:1, lucky_no:5},
{id:2, name:"Mary May", progress:70, gender:"female", rating:2, col:"blue", dob:"9/10/20220", car:2, lucky_no:10},
{id:3, name:"Chris", progress:50, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"red", dob:"14/04/1984", car:2, lucky_no:5},
{id:4, name:"Sourav", progress:10, gender:"female", rating:2, col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982", car:true, lucky_no:10},
{id:5, name:"Dev", progress:30, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"red", dob:"14/04/1984", car:2, lucky_no:5},
{id:6, name:"May", progress:1, gender:"female", rating:2, col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982", car:true, lucky_no:10},
{id:7, name:"Joker", progress:8, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"red", dob:"14/04/1984", car:2, lucky_no:5},
{id:8, name:"Balcky", progress:1, gender:"female", rating:2, col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982", car:true, lucky_no:10},
{id:9, name:"Browny", progress:18, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"red", dob:"14/04/1984", car:2, lucky_no:5},
{id:10, name:"Shaun", progress:90, gender:"female", rating:2, col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982", car:true, lucky_no:10},
{id:11, name:"Ram", progress:100, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"red", dob:"14/04/1984", car:1, lucky_no:5},
{id:12, name:"Krish", progress:71, gender:"female", rating:2, col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982", car:true, lucky_no:10},
{id:13, name:"Ravan", progress:18, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"red", dob:"14/04/1984", car:1, lucky_no:5},
{id:14, name:"Karnan", progress:81, gender:"female", rating:2, col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982", car:true, lucky_no:10},
{id:15, name:"Dhur", progress:62, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"red", dob:"14/04/1984", car:1, lucky_no:5},


];


//load sample data into the table
table.setData(tabledata);


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Oli Folkerd, thank you for your help,  i tried with the code but still i'm facing issue with the date range filter (the filters itself hidden). i have added source code for your reference! Once again i thank you for your help